# Is there any way to store and resend messages in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any way to store and resend messages in wso2 . I uses message store and message processor to send message to a end point .

But with this I was having no manual control over the messages sending . what if I need to send those messages again mannualy at some later time .

Please help

Regards
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

You can enable vfs transport and set the PollInterval to send the message after manual time setting.The vfs transport is enabled by removings vfs related tags in axis2 file.and the property that is used for PollInterval is :

```
 <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
```